# JNI String Corruption

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I'm getting weird string corruption across JNI calls which is causing problems on the the Java side. Every so often, I'll get a corrupted string in the passed array, which sometimes has existing parts of the original non-corrupted string. The original C++ code was supposed to set the first index of the array to the address. The second version uses a direct buffer, because I was trying to fix the problem. The simulator runs in a separate thread from the application threads, with application threads posting events to be executed.

I thought before, also, that because I was preallocating the buffer, it might be getting used more than once if multiple threads access the socket, with that causing corruption, so I switched it over for a Mina IoBuffer which is allocated from a pool, with the backing ByteBuffer available. However, it does not seem to have made any difference.

```
remoteaddress[0]: 10.1.1.2:49153
remoteaddress[0]: 10.1.4.2:49153
remoteaddress[0]: 10.1.6.2:49153
remoteaddress[0]: 10.1.2.2:49153
remoteaddress[0]: 10.1.9.2:49153
remoteaddress[0]: {garbage here}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kokuks.KKSAddress.<init>(KKSAddress.java:139)
    at kokuks.KKSAddress.createAddress(KKSAddress.java:48)
    at kokuks.KKSSocket._recvFrom(KKSSocket.java:963)
    at kokuks.scheduler.RecvOperation$1.execute(RecvOperation.java:144)
    at kokuks.scheduler.RecvOperation$1.execute(RecvOperation.java:1)
    at kokuks.KKSEvent.run(KKSEvent.java:58)
    at kokuks.KokuKS.handleJNIEventExpiry(KokuKS.java:872)
    at kokuks.KokuKS.handleJNIEventExpiry_fjni(KokuKS.java:880)
    at kokuks.KokuKS.runSimulator_jni(Native Method)
    at kokuks.KokuKS$1.run(KokuKS.java:773)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
remoteaddress[0]: 10.1.7.2:49153
```

The null pointer exception comes from trying to use the corrupt string. In C++, the address prints to standard out normally, but doing this reduces the rate of errors, from what I can see.

The C++ code:

```
/*
 * Class:     kokuks_KKSSocket
 * Method:    recvFrom2_jni
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;IIJ)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_kokuks_KKSSocket_recvFrom2_1jni
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring sockpath, jobject addrbuf, jobject buf, jint position, jint limit, jlong flags) {

    const char* cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(sockpath, NULL);
    std::string spath = std::string(cstr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(sockpath, cstr); // release me!

    if (KKS_DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    ns3::Ptr<ns3::Object> sockobj = refmap[spath];
    ns3::Ptr<ns3::Socket> socket = ns3::DynamicCast<ns3::Socket>(sockobj);
    if (!socket) {
        std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " socket not found for path!!" << std::endl;
        return -1; // not found
    }

    if (!addrbuf) {
        std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " sender address directbuffer address is null!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t* bufaddr = (uint8_t*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buf);
    long bufcap = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(buf);
    uint8_t* realbufaddr = bufaddr + position;
    uint32_t remaining = limit - position;

    uint8_t* addrbufaddr = (uint8_t*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(addrbuf);
    long addrbufcap = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(buf);

    if (KKS_DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " bufaddr: " << bufaddr << ", cap: " << bufcap << std::endl;
    }

    ns3::Address aaddr;
    uint32_t mflags = flags;

    int ret = socket->RecvFrom(realbufaddr, remaining, mflags, aaddr);

    if (ret > 0) {
        if (KKS_DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " addr: " << aaddr << std::endl;
        }
        ns3::InetSocketAddress insa = ns3::InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(aaddr);

        std::stringstream ss;
        insa.GetIpv4().Print(ss);
        ss << ":" << insa.GetPort() << std::ends;

        if (KKS_DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " addr: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
        }

        const char *cstr = ss.str().c_str();
        char *dst = (char*)addrbufaddr;
        size_t len = strlen(cstr);
        strncpy(dst, cstr, len + 1);

        if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
            env->ExceptionDescribe();
        }
    }

    jint jret = ret;

    return jret;
}

/*
 * Class:     kokuks_KKSNode
 * Method:    node_getID_jni
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_kokuks_KKSNode_node_1getID_1jni
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring path) {

    const char* cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, NULL);
    std::string spath = std::string(cstr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, cstr); // release me!

    if (KKS_DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "[kks-c~" << spath << "?] " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    ns3::Ptr<ns3::Object> nodeobj = refmap[spath];
    ns3::Ptr<ns3::Node> node = ns3::DynamicCast<ns3::Node>(nodeobj);
    if (node) {
        uint32_t id   = node->GetId();
        jint     j_id = id;
        return j_id;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The Java code (if it helps):

```
/**
 *
 * @param remoteaddress
 * @param bytes
 * @param flags
 * @return
 */
protected int _core_recvFrom(final KKSAddress[] remoteaddress, final ByteBuffer bytes, final long flags) throws IOException {
    if (!kks.isRealtime() || kks.isSimulationThread()) {
        return _core_recvFrom_st(remoteaddress, bytes, flags);
    }

    boolean usejnibb = !bytes.isDirect();
    final IoBuffer iob;

    final ByteBuffer mybuf;
    if (usejnibb) {
        if (USE_IOB) {
            iob = IoBuffer.allocate(bytes.remaining(), true);
            mybuf = iob.buf();
        } else {
            mybuf = jnibb;
        }
        mybuf.clear();
        mybuf.limit(bytes.remaining());
    } else {
        mybuf = bytes;
        iob = null;
    }
    try {
        KKSEvent<Integer> kev = new KKSSocketEvent<Integer>(this) {
            @Override
            protected Integer execute(long timeMS) throws IOException {
                return _core_recvFrom_st(remoteaddress, mybuf, flags);
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see kokuks.KKSEvent#getType()
             */
            public String getType() {
                return "_core_recvFrom()";
            }
        };
        try {
            int ret = kks.scheduleEventRTWait(kev);
            if (ret > 0 && usejnibb) {
                mybuf.flip();
                bytes.put(mybuf);
            }
            return ret;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new InterruptedIOException();
        } catch (EventExecException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException)e.getCause();
            }
            throw new IOException(e.getCause());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    } finally {
        if (usejnibb) {
            if (USE_IOB) {
                iob.free();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Pass an array of size 1 into remote address, and this will be set with
 * the sender of the packet (hax). This emulates C++ references.
 *
 * @param remoteaddress
 * @param buf
 * @param flags
 * @return
 */
protected int _core_recvFrom_st(final KKSAddress[] remoteaddress, ByteBuffer buf, long flags) throws IOException {
    try {
        _syncJNI();

        boolean recvfrom = remoteaddress != null;

        errNo = SocketErrno.ERROR_NOTERROR;

        ByteBuffer mybuf = buf;

        if (!buf.isDirect()) {
            errNo = SocketErrno.ERROR_BUFFERNOTDIRECT;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer not direct!");
        }

        final IoBuffer iob;
        ByteBuffer bb = null;
        if (recvfrom) {
            if (USE_IOB) {
                iob = IoBuffer.allocate(128, true);
                bb = iob.buf();
            } else {
                bb = addrbb;
            }
            bb.clear();
        } else {
            iob = null;
        }

        try {

            //IoBuffer pre = IoBuffer.wrap(mybuf.duplicate());

            //printMessage("sockrecv (pre) // rxavailable: " + getRxAvailable());

            // use new mechanism
            int ret = recvfrom ?
                recvFrom2_jni(
                path.toPortableString(),
                bb,
                mybuf,
                mybuf.position(),
                mybuf.limit(),
                flags
            ) : recv_jni(
                path.toPortableString(),
                mybuf,
                mybuf.position(),
                mybuf.limit(),
                flags
            );

            _syncJNI();

            if (ret >= 0) {
                rxTotal += ret;

                /*
                printMessage("local addr: " + LOCAL_ADDR + ", real local addr: " + getRemoteAddress().toNormalAddress());
                printMessage("remote addr: " + REMOTE_ADDR + ", real remote addr: " + getApp().getNode().getIPV4Address());


                if (
                    getType() == SOCKET_TYPE_TCP &&
                    getRemoteAddress().toNormalAddress().equals(LOCAL_ADDR) &&
                    getApp().getNode().getIPV4Address().equals(REMOTE_ADDR)
                ) {
                    mrTest_testRecvd(mybuf, ret);
                }
                */

                //printMessage("sockrecv // mybuf: " + mybuf + ", ret: " + ret + " rxavailable: " + getRxAvailable() + ", data: " + BufUtils.asText(mybuf, ret));

                buf.position(buf.position() + ret);

                if (recvfrom) {
                    String st;
                    try {
                        st = IoBuffer.wrap(bb).getString(CDE);
                        remoteaddress[0] = KKSAddress.createAddress(st);
                        if (remoteaddress[0] == null) {
                            System.out.println("warning; remote address is null!! original: " + st);
                        }
                    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return ret;

                //pre.limit(pre.position() + ret);
                //printMessage("_core_recvFrom_st recvd from " + ((!recvfrom || remoteaddress[0] == null || remoteaddress == null) ? getRemoteAddress() : remoteaddress[0]) + ": " + pre.getHexDump());
            }
            throw new IOException("I/O exception, retval: " + ret + ", errNo: " + errNo);
        } finally {
            if (recvfrom) {
                if (USE_IOB) {
                    iob.free();
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        errNo = _getErrNo();
    }
}
```

Edit: I also identified that packet data was getting corrupted. Also, the problem happens on my work PC more than my home PC. My work PC runs Windows XP, has 4GB RAM and has a Q6600, my home PC has an overclocked Q6600, 4GB RAM, and runs Windows 7 64-bit, although it is with 32-bit Java.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem, one year on, in the exact same method (more or less). Really annoying. There is full thread-safetiness, and my knowledge of threading aspects has increased tenfold. However, I still get this problem. I doubt it is anything to do with threads. All variables are on the stack.

Comment: I see quite a few issues w/ the code, `addrbb` is shared, so you'd like it to be a ThreadLocal<ByteBuffer>. You do not check for NULL result in the C code (but that should be a minor one) and generally the stanadard way to pass ByteBuffer is to treat ByteBuffer.address like `void*` in C. One more note: ByteBuffer in java are at least a page size (usually 4k) allocated. `ByteBuffer.duplicate` just creates java object at the same underlying backing area, so it's useless in your case, you can use ByteBuffer.slice if you won't to conserve address space.

Comment: IoBuffer uses a ThreadLocal ByteBuffer allocation pool :) I think the problem might have been using a Java value directly instead of doing the conversion on a different line. 

    long bufcap = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(buf);
    uint8_t* realbufaddr = bufaddr + position;

I've seen problems in the past where I've tried to do it on a single line, and the app fails (mostly for return values, however). 

    jlong j_bufcap = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(buf);
    long bufcap = j_bufcap;
    uint8_t* realbufaddr = bufaddr + position;

May have fixed it, but more testing is required.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code but I am assuming it to be a character encoding issue. Try using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` or something like that. Sorry can't help much at this moment, but this should give you a starting point, I guess.

Comment: Not sure, why would it give me garbage strings every so often rather than all the time? Perhaps it's a memory allocation issue. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn´t be thread-safetiness issues? Try to synchronize the access to the native methods.

Comment: I think this does sort it out, but isn't JNI supposed to be thread safe?

Comment: I really don't know if JNI is thread safe, but if the C++ DLL is not, the whole solution will not be thread safe.

Comment: Hmm, well, the C++ DLL should be thread safe, there's a mutex on the event functions contained within which are called from the Java side. I suppose that only leaves the JNI mechanism which could have the problem.